# Lazy loading について

Tags: c#

Lazy loading について日本語で解説されたサンプルはどこかにありますか？
下記の例を見つけたどけ全部英語です。

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/116273/A-Generic-Way-to-Delay-load-Lazy-load-Any-Number-o

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275932/Lazy-Loading-in-Csharp

Comment: 前者はASP.NET Ajax、後者はCLRプロパティの実装についての解説で方向性が大きく異なりますがどちらでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

今更UpdatePanelもないと思いますので、[MSDNによる`Lazy<T>`の解説](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/dd997286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)を貼っておきます。要するにコンストラクタに`Func<T>`を渡すと`Value`への初回アクセス時に実行されるというだけのことです。